# How many vim do I have?

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

I am on Mac, El Capitan.

Here are my code:

[image]

My question is: **how many vim do I have?** I know that:

1. /usr/bin/vim  is from Mac OSX
2. /usr/local/bin/vim  is from Homebrew
3. /usr/local/Cellar/vim/xxx/bin/vim  is also from Homebrew (?)

Also:

[image]

[image]

So another question: **Which one should I use**, if I want to use brew to upgrade it.

Comment: Use the latest version.  A huge number of bugs have been fixed lately.  A comparatively much smaller number of bugs have been added. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura Hi thanks! It seems /usr/local/bin/vim is recommended. However, I am wondering how to uninstall the one at /usr/local/Cellar/vim/xxx/bin/vim, and more importantly, what's the difference between those two? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the one in `/usr/local/bin` by making sure your PATH environment variable includes `/usr/local/bin` **before** `/usr/bin`.

If you look carefully, you will see that `/usr/local/bin/vim` is a symbolic link to `homebrew`'s *Cellar* and each time you update `vim` in `homebrew` it will update the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` to point to the latest version in its *Cellar*. So, if you use `/usr/local/bin/vim` you will always be using the latest.

Let's check that:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/vim
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin  30 21 Jul 18:25 /usr/local/bin/vim -> ../Cellar/vim/7.4.2033/bin/vim
```

Yes, `/usr/local/bin/vim` points to `/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.2033/bin/vim` and that is why you get the same version when you run both commands - because they are the same thing.

The Apple-shipped version is ancient - you don't want that.

Comment: That true! I forget to check /usr/local/bin/vim but have checked /Cellar/vim/xxx/bin/vim. Thanks for your help!